# How to add a linebreak in test::base/test::nginx/perl test case?

Tags: perl, nginx, testing, apache-apisix

I was writing test cases while implementing a feature in [Apache APISIX](https://apisix.apache.org) where I came across a stubborn error where there is an extra linebreak in the "got" part in comparison to the "expected" part.

[image: Test result]

Here is the code for the test:

```perl
=== TEST 8: get value from vault: token env var wrong/missing
--- config
    location /t {
        content_by_lua_block {
            local vault = require("apisix.secret.vault")
            local conf = {
                prefix = "kv/apisix",
                token = "$ENV://VALT_TOKEN",
                uri = "http://127.0.0.1:8200"
            }
            local value, err = vault.get(conf, "/apisix-key/jack/key")
            if err then
                return ngx.say(err)
            end

            ngx.print("value")
        }
    }
--- request
GET /t
--- response_body
failed to decode result, res: {"errors":["permission denied"]}



=== TEST 9: get value from vault: token env var contains wrong token
--- config
    location /t {
        content_by_lua_block {
            local vault = require("apisix.secret.vault")
            local conf = {
                prefix = "kv/apisix",
                token = "$ENV://WRONG_VAULT_TOKEN",
                uri = "http://127.0.0.1:8200"
            }
            local value, err = vault.get(conf, "/apisix-key/jack/key")
            if err then
                return ngx.say(err)
            end

            ngx.print("value")
        }
    }
--- request
GET /t
--- response_body
failed to decode result, res: {"errors":["permission denied"]}
```

I tried adding "\n" at the end of the expected part like so:

```perl
--- response_body
failed to decode result, res: {"errors":["permission denied"]}\n
```

But that didn't work. So I tried to surround the "expected" part in quotes `"..."` so that the linebreak gets included that didn't work either.

Another approach would be to remove the linebreak from the "got" part by writing some code but I think that wouldn't be an ideal thing to do (modifying the response).

Thanks in advance!!

Here's the [link](https://github.com/apache/apisix/actions/runs/4201938502/jobs/7289480063) to the workflow action run.

Comment: When I have these problems, I usually remove all trailing whitespace from the output I want to test if that whitespace not important to the problem.

Comment: @briandfoy the geek inside me does not allow me to modify the output in any way. He thinks that it is a bad engineering practice lol.

Comment: I'd think that same inner geek would make you match the output exactly then. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was simple! I didn't know we could use regex to match "got" with "expected". This is how I did it.

I replaced this:

```perl
--- response_body
failed to decode result, res: {"errors":["permission denied"]}
```

With this:

```perl
--- response_body_like
failed to decode result, res: {\"errors\":\[\"permission denied\"\]}\n
```

The idea was to use the `response_body_like` construct to be able to use regex for expression matching. Thanks to [this blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20230110102334/https://api7.ai/learning-center/openresty/all-inclusive-testing-methods-test-nginx).